# Looping workers trough an Agent-based list of IP addresses

Tags: loops, recursion, elixir

I am working on an Elixir-based network scanner.
My goal is to be able to store the list of IP addresses in a Agent (easy) and to loop workers on this Agent so they fetch the head of the list and launch the scanning/probing function (not so easy).
While this might sound as some kind of theoric stuff, I can provide code snippets if it helps.

EDIT: Apparently I managed to figure out how to do so (I guess that's how one would have done so).

```
defmodule Find3r.Worker do
use GenServer
require Logger

  def start_link, do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :worker)

  def init(:ok) do
    Logger.debug("Worker activated.")
    {:ok, :ok}
  end

  def scan_range(range), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:scan_range, range})

  def handle_call({:scan_range, range}, _from, :ok) do
    Logger.debug("Scanning #{range}")
    {:ok, pid} = Agent.start(Find3r.Utils, :addresses_for, [range])
    Agent.get_and_update(pid, fn(state) -> foo(state) end) |> loop(pid)
    {:reply, :ok, :ok}
  end


  # Avoids an exception when the Agent runs out of addresses
  defp foo([ip|rest]), do: {ip, rest}
  defp foo(_),         do: {[], []}

  defp loop(ip, pid) when is_tuple(ip) do
    spawn(Find3r.Utils, :scan, [ip])
    Agent.get_and_update(pid, fn(state) -> foo(state) end) |> loop(pid)
  end
  defp loop(_, _), do: nil


end
```

The project has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/Annwenn/Find3r/).
Thanks again o/

Comment: Please do provide code snippets and try to boil down your problem to something very specific - that way it's much easier to write a useful answer

Comment: The problem is simple: I don't know how to make a finite number of workers (such as the one [here](https://git.yt/AnneGwenn/Find3r/src/master/lib/find3r/worker.ex)) taking the head of the list, passing it to the `Find3r.Utils.scan/1` function and returning the tail to the Agent that stores the list of IP addresses.

Comment: Please post the code in the question and try to make the question self-contained, without the need to follow external links, read comments, and so on

Comment: You should check out `poolboy`. Here's a [quick tutorial](http://hashnuke.com/2013/10/03/managing-processes-with-poolboy-in-elixir.html).

Comment: In spite of clear requests to add code snippets to clarify the question no such snippets have been added.  Vote to close.

Comment: Well, I have trouble figuring out how to [properly insert code in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), so if you don't want a nice formatting from Gogs, here's the code:  

defmodule Find3r.Worker do
      def scan(range) do
        [ip|rest] = range
        Agent.get_and_update(__MODULE__, fn -> {ip, rest} end)
        Find3r.Utils.scan(ip)
        scan(rest)
      end
    end

Comment: @knrz I used this tutorial, but I was more interested in a plain Elixir solution using it's standard library. Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to do so (I guess that's how one would have done so).

```
defmodule Find3r.Worker do
use GenServer
require Logger

  def start_link, do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :worker)

  def init(:ok) do
    Logger.debug("Worker activated.")
    {:ok, :ok}
  end

  def scan_range(range), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:scan_range, range})

  def handle_call({:scan_range, range}, _from, :ok) do
    Logger.debug("Scanning #{range}")
    {:ok, pid} = Agent.start(Find3r.Utils, :addresses_for, [range])
    Agent.get_and_update(pid, fn(state) -> foo(state) end) |> loop(pid)
    {:reply, :ok, :ok}
  end


  # Avoids an exception when the Agent runs out of addresses
  defp foo([ip|rest]), do: {ip, rest}
  defp foo(_),         do: {[], []}

  defp loop(ip, pid) when is_tuple(ip) do
    spawn(Find3r.Utils, :scan, [ip])
    Agent.get_and_update(pid, fn(state) -> foo(state) end) |> loop(pid)
  end
  defp loop(_, _), do: nil


end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (hack-ish) way to do what [I think] you've described:

```
defmodule MultiScanner do
  def scan(range) do
    main_proc = self
    Enum.each(range, fn(ip) -> 
                       spawn_link(fn -> 
                         res = Find3r.Utils.scan(ip)
                         send main_proc, {:ip_results, ip, res}
                       end)
                     end)
    ip_map = Enum.map(range, fn(ip) -> {ip, nil} end)
             |> Enum.into(%{})
    wait_for_results(ip_map)
  end

  defp wait_for_results(ip_map, acc \\ %{})
  defp wait_for_results(ip_map, acc) when map_size(ip_map) == 0, do: acc
  defp wait_for_results(ip_map, acc) do
    receive do
      {:ip_results, ip, res} ->
        acc = Map.put(acc, ip, res)
        ip_map = Map.delete(ip_map, ip)
        wait_for_results(ip_map, acc)
    end
  end
end
```

This spawns a process for each IP address, which runs the scans, and sends the result back to the calling process, which in turn collapses the results to a map of ip => result.

There are obviously a multitude of problems with this approach- most obvious is that you probably don't want *all* your scans starting simultaneously.

There are a bunch of ways to solve this problem, but aside from a canned solution like `poolboy`, as suggested in the comments, or `:gproc` - if I were going to actually implement a robust solution to this approach, I would probably put together a supervision tree something like this:

```
Scan.Supervisor
  -ScanWorker.Supervisor (simple-one-for-one)
      -ScanWorker (anon GenServer, executing a single scan)
      -ScanWorker 
      ...
  -ScanWorker.Manager (Named GenServer, coordinates the ScanWorkers)
```

My back of the envelope architecture would have the 4 modules above, plus a top level module `Scan` to hold the public API.  I also imagine it would require an hour or so to flesh it all out to the point where I wouldn't be embarrassed to show it to a co-worker.

I started to sketch that out for you- but frankly, your question is vague and poorly written.  You don't seem to have spent much time writing it, or even bothered to proofread it. The answer I've put together here is probably more generous of my time than your question deserves: I think you'll find much better success on SO if you spend more time and effort writing your question.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thank you for your answer,  Chris.
My question is poorly written because English isn't my native language, and I can't say I'm used to express myself with technical terms with it (and  a programming language which I do not grasp all the concepts).

However, I recently found a kind of [solution](https://github.com/Annwenn/Find3r/blob/master/lib/find3r/worker.ex#L14-L19) for that. Feel free to take a look at it if clicking on an external link doesn't scandalizes you.
It uses an Agent, and surprisingly the VM handles a /16 very well.
Have a nice day.

Comment: If you've found a good solution, you may want to write it up as an answer here, and accept it so that others can benefit from your research.  Glad you were able to find an acceptable solution.